# Proxmox external VM / CT access

Tags: vps, dedicated-server, openvz, proxmox

I've just begun the setup of proxmox for our none profit educational VPS service. However, the problem we're facing is a lack of IPv4 addresses available to us.

Is it possible to route a sub-domain to the host servers IP address and then get that forwarded to the individual containers accordingly. For example:

```
SSH root@node-123.w-a-s-d.me
```

Will allow a client with the VM ID of 123 to access their server 
And the same goes for things like: node-123.w-a-s-d.me
This would be the web address allowing any applications running on port 80 for that specific node

I'm unsure how to go about this and have looked online with no luck. I hope our goal is clear. I look forward to hearing from you. Josh

Answer (score 0):

Exposing SSH that way will not be easy as you can only have one thing listening on port 22 for every given IP address, and while you could just adding random ports to each VPS and the forward it from primary box which holds public IP (and vms are behind nat) this is not exactly the best solution.

What you may want to do instead is set up one public-facing box that people can ssh into via public IP and from it SSH to subsequent private machines by their internal IP. Alternatively you can set that box with openVPN and set it to assign internal IP address to anyone connecting via it. While openVPN takes more time to set up right, it can come with it's own DNS so when connected to it calling out `SSH root@node-123.w-a-s-d.me` will automatically route you to the private IP address rather than the shared public facing one.

With HTTP this is much easier as you can set up a proxy on the front-facing machines which then proxies requests for given sub domain to specific internal IP address.